# Dynamically change favicon in React (To send the website address in whatsapp)

Tags: reactjs, whatsapp, favicon, react-helmet

In the website which I created in React.js, I give my users the ability to create their own page, input some data and a logo image.
Now, I want to have that logo as a favicon for the page, and when they send the website in Whatsapp, it will have the dynamic favicon of the image the user uploaded, instead of the general favicon.

So, I did managed to change the favicon of the page (Using react-favicon npm), but the favicon image not changed in Whatsapp sending.

For example: [This is the website of the user.](https://bucard.co.il/digitalCard/%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8-HAL)

As you can see, the favicon according to the logo the user input.

And now, [This is the whatsapp screenshot when sending the url](http://prntscr.com/tw7cur)
(The "Bu" favicon dispalys there is the generally favicon of the website).

**P.S. I just notice that the title and content I replace using React Helmet, also not working on whatsapp, so maybe it relates somehow.**

Thank you!

Comment: Are you doing server side rendering? i dont think whatsapp will actually run the javascript on the page so you get to see the correct overrides

Comment: You are not. if you disable javascript on your site you can see what whatsapp grabs

Comment: @eltonkamami What do you mean? Can't I do it?

Comment: anybody ???????